# Spring Saml2 and Spring Session - SavedRequest not retrieved (cannot redirect to requested page after authentication / InResponseTo exception)

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml, spring-session, opensaml, spring-security-saml2

I am trying to use Spring Boot SAML2 + Spring Session to secure my web application (to be deployed on K8S).  Everything is fine without spring-session-data-rest or spring-session-hazelcast.  It can authenticate with Okta and redirect back to the requested page after authentication.  Also, I can use either opensaml3 or opensaml4.

However, when I tried to use either spring-session-data-rest or spring-session-hazelcast (just 1 instance, no cluster yet), it would not redirect back to the requested page.  Also, it'd fail with opensaml4 with exception: "The response contained an InResponseTo attribute [] but no saved authentication request was found".  There's some mentioning about opensaml3 going EOL so I want to make it work with opensaml4.

Here's a sample application to demonstrate my case https://github.com/simonckw/redis-saml2/tree/redis.  Have I missed anything?  Have anyone got a working sample with this setup?  Help is much appreciated.

p.s. I've traced into HttpSessionRequestCache.java, invoked from SavedRequestAwareWarpper.java.  Without spring-session-data-rest or spring-session-hazelcast, the saved request can be retrieved but not when either spring-session-data-rest or spring-session-hazelcast is enabled. It also seems to me that the InResponseTo exception could be related too.  My Redis setup should be fine.  Here's the session data written into Redis:

1. "spring:session:sessions:expires:7c1858d1-0ea7-4a7a-8523-2abf89137771"
2. "spring:session:expirations:1654439580000"
3. "spring:session:sessions:expires:58a584d3-625e-4e0a-bef5-3aaff485ad93"
4. "spring:session:index:org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME:abc@xyz.com"
5. "spring:session:sessions:7c1858d1-0ea7-4a7a-8523-2abf89137771"
6. "spring:session:sessions:58a584d3-625e-4e0a-bef5-3aaff485ad93"

127.0.0.1:6379> hkeys spring:session:sessions:7c1858d1-0ea7-4a7a-8523-2abf89137771

1. "sessionAttr:SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST"
2. "lastAccessedTime"
3. "maxInactiveInterval"
4. "creationTime"
5. "sessionAttr:org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.HttpSessionSaml2AuthenticationRequestRepository.SAML2_AUTHN_REQUEST"

127.0.0.1:6379> hkeys spring:session:sessions:58a584d3-625e-4e0a-bef5-3aaff485ad93

1. "maxInactiveInterval"
2. "creationTime"
3. "lastAccessedTime"
4. "sessionAttr:SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT"
5. "sessionAttr:SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that Spring Session is setting `SameSite=Lax` for its `SESSION` cookie. Your servlet container isn't setting that on `JSESSIONID` (when you're not using Spring Session).

Because the SAML response is being POSTed from Okta's page, the browser will not send the cookie, so Spring doesn't think it has a session in which to find the authentication request. It uses that saved request to reconcile the `InResponseTo` attribute.

You can work around this by removing `SameSite` from the cookie. Create a bean like this:

```
    @Bean
    public DefaultCookieSerializerCustomizer cookieSerializerCustomizer() {
        return cookieSerializer -> {
            cookieSerializer.setSameSite(null);
        };
    }
```

Alternatively, you could explicitly specify `None`, but then you would have to also set the `Secure` attribute.

Note: Chrome is supposed to default to `Lax` where `SameSite` isn't specified. In reality, it doesn't do that if `HttpOnly` is set. Safari and Firefox don't even seem to care about `HttpOnly`.

This problem is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60096206/2599745).

Comment: Thanks! It worked. The working version: [link](https://github.com/simonckw/redis-saml2)

Comment: another solution, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74435518/spring-security-saml2-provider-inresponseto-validation-for-saml2-executed-even/75079341#75079341