# Spring security saml2 provider: InResponseTo validation for saml2 executed even if saved request is not found

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0

With spring security saml2 provider version 5.7.x mandatory validation of InResponseTo was introduced if it is provided in the authentication response.

Validation logic expects to find saved Saml2AuthenticationRequest in HttpSession. However that is only possible if SameSite attribute is not set.

According security requirements of current project I'm working on it is set to Lax or Strict. This configuration is done outside of the application. This causes loss of the session and request data.

Maybe someone already have dealed with an issue and knows how to deal with it? I don't see any way to disable validation or alternative way of saving request available in the library.

Answer (score 7):

While upgrading spring security from 5.x to 6, I ran into the same issue with spring session cookie. There doesn't seem to be any standard solution for this. For now, I have provided an implementation of `Saml2AuthenticationRequestRepository` which saves the SAML request in database based on **RelayState** parameter. Following is the sample implementation using Mongo. Any backend (In-memory cache, Redis, MySQL etc.) can be used  -

```
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.core.Saml2ParameterNames;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.AbstractSaml2AuthenticationRequest;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.Saml2AuthenticationRequestRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class MongoSaml2AuthenticationRequestRepository implements Saml2AuthenticationRequestRepository<AbstractSaml2AuthenticationRequest> {

    public static final String SAML2_REQUEST_COLLECTION = "saml2RequestsRepository";
    private final @NonNull MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    
    @Override
    public AbstractSaml2AuthenticationRequest loadAuthenticationRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        
        String relayState = request.getParameter(Saml2ParameterNames.RELAY_STATE);
        if (relayState == null) {
            return null;
        }
        
        log.debug("Fetching SAML2 Authentication Request by relay state : {}", relayState.get());
        Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("relayState").is(relayState.get()));
        AbstractSaml2AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, AbstractSaml2AuthenticationRequest.class, SAML2_REQUEST_COLLECTION);
        
        if (!authenticationRequest.getRelayState().equals(relayState.get())) {
            log.error("Relay State received from request '{}' is different from saved request '{}'.", relayState.get(), authenticationRequest.getRelayState());
            return null;
        }
        
        log.debug("SAML2 Request retrieved : {}", authenticationRequest);
        return authenticationRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveAuthenticationRequest(AbstractSaml2AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        
        //As per OpenSamlAuthenticationRequestResolver, it will always have value. However, one validation can be added to check for null and regenerate.
        String relayState = authenticationRequest.getRelayState();
        log.debug("Relay State Received: {}", relayState);
        mongoTemplate.save(authenticationRequest, SAML2_REQUEST_COLLECTION);
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractSaml2AuthenticationRequest removeAuthenticationRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        
        AbstractSaml2AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest = loadAuthenticationRequest(request);
        if (authenticationRequest == null) {
            return null;
        }
        
        mongoTemplate.remove(authenticationRequest, SAML2_REQUEST_COLLECTION);
        return authenticationRequest;
    }

}
```

Post adding this, all the SAML validations including InResponseTo validation are passed successfully. Since **RelayState** is not supposed to change between SAML requests as per specifications, this seemed like reasonable alternative (in absence of any standard solution so far). I am running this through standard security testing and will update the solution with my findings if any.

Comment: How do you autowire this into Spring Boot SAML2 filter chain?

Comment: @Dennis you just expose it as a bean of type `Saml2AuthenticationRequestRepository`

Comment: Nice solution! I did something similar, but instead of saving it into the relayState I saved the inResponse code in a separate cookie (with sameSite=None) which is set by the implementation of the Saml2AuthenticationRequestRepository. Either is fine, but if an identity provider doesn't send the relaystate back (or uses it for something else, I think some use it for redirects), it is a good alternative.