# SAML error on subsequent requests related The response contained an InResponseTo attribute [] but no saved authentication request was found

Tags: spring-boot, saml-2.0, okta, spring-saml

I have implemented SAML and Okta integration for my spring boot application. It is a SP initiated flow. Everything was working fine until it got deployed on the server.

Am getting this error "The response contained an InResponseTo attribute [ARQ641560b-ff8c-482d-8ca7-a54e6234b503] but no saved authentication request was found"
This happens only for the first request to the application and subsequent requests work fine.
I also noticed that this was not an issue when I was running it on localhost:8080.

I saw this solution to similar error [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72508155/spring-saml2-and-spring-session-savedrequest-not-retrieved-cannot-redirect-to) but I want to know why it works on subsequent requests and fails when its accessed for the first time in my case.
When I look at SAML Tracer, I see in the subsequent requests SameSite = None is set.

`set-cookie: JSESSIONID=260D515A94B959A63A22FC1BF71D1994; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly set-cookie: idx=eyJ6aXAiOiJERUYiLCJhbGlhcyI6ImVuY3J5cHRpb25rZXkiLCJ2ZXIiOiIxIiwib2lkIjoiMDBvY3AxdmpqYzczN3N2OUo1ZDciLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiZGlyIn0..sAxhWKiCPv6NIAUb.xIXFMU1YkSS-7MZptweGbx-0r82j8Xk9nm4ZLrOsDyfA9iZu_qR4WcQJTokMnqTgt-1QlJ7DyCVs08faW_V5QAYURcoGhQ-D6R9U11AeKdaFBVGlHuloVDh8y_9-AW_lbxkQT6qdcu-O9F_NlBqtpSLBP-rMH4AqV4MU5HxHdavGxuNY0VOvYYsBx9rFqJ0Y1egup5m7upwXEKR6C08I4CX2mlOPTqjwZb-3rIN3oaI4cVqNZpU44tAANe3bX_L9GJqfnHW3Mg30TfBYG-wOhLQn8MGs1p7kAuPpUBbisW7eUu_QJI6cGWls5xvY3PflZBjMnFnBTOceZVD756wcQY8xipnfuUicVIo5cnwckaOYFAzlHrlSNBzKOHf3WSEA1E4XiyP8zwLzOzk5k67P4lDOC9uW9mc9ZyWxkBk8eLZUqXEP-gMaP-ZNqK6mol5mB4MNdgx4hR-Xj64gaq8vIDubq5SL0OIF1l9aMdaAwQPipJ5OCFOXSXISKi40EjI1o18ugmiLguRth8JzgmjtIJ3oPGhIyWXQGEWXxG41ZLYVliIo0CaEWVerw1zFdeml_SUVLIUKaVMDXsrqdrsfYL4ZPFoLhFvWx9DPamaiq8YJiF7B0350-TXLyBdXLiYaCSo0viSJH4GeACduYAUsECtMasVl7StFa1YXP35lhI8xsrGc-YAhtNbfVM_EZiYeudVW2odj52nzxq-bpwpKkn_ZoW-hI9aOyWUHu8AfokPI34MP3pqonmPYbtvV1yO0TQb7Bdb52Z5ptmpr-10qikZZb6FNg-V6q8aJEt8j-I1MhkswZ-pZyvk3iCzzEiv672BkifZ5qyRse23rg7yX840LK2Ln-1qHA2-Ch_3xI4Z_LRPF5Ti9iHkfdgmnWpv1DsaN6NRjnwqiICGiml7iBwLPIaR9euahkWlbdEodG4tphGIjSOST2hvd9f6bsfus06u5wxNL.d5YRi8qlZW70SYSKv7gF_A;Version=1;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly;SameSite=None`

How do I go about solving this ?